# d3.js 'mousewheel' event is NOT working on Firefox (it works only in Chrome, Safari and IE browsers)

Tags: firefox, d3.js

The 'mousewheel.zoom' event (of 'd3.js')  IS NOT WORKING on Firefox browser (I got the latest version of FF).

Here is a little piece of code that I'm using in order to REMOVE THE MOUSEWHEEL EVENT from my maps:

function draw_data_center(file_name){

```
d3.json(file_name, function(json) {

  d3.select("#div_data_center svg").remove();

  vis = d3.select("#div_data_center").append("svg")

      .attr("width", $("#div_data_center").width())

      .attr("height", $("#div_data_center").height())

      .attr("pointer-events", "all")

      .append('svg:g')

      .call(zoom.on("zoom", redraw))

      .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)  //in this line of code I removed the 'mousewheel' functionality BUT it doesn't work in Firefox browser (the other browsers work correctly)

      .on("click.zoom", null)

      .on("touchstart.zoom", null)

      .append('svg:g').......(etc...ect)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: You can have a look at this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you fixed your problem yet, but I stumbled across your page while trying to find the answer.

I found a lot of documentation stating that, for Firefox, setting "DOMMouseScroll.zoom" to null fixes the problem. However, it seems that FireFox has changed how they detect the scroll wheel. Here is your code, modified, to include the fix:

```
vis = d3.select("#div_data_center").append("svg")
      .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
      .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", null) // disables older versions of Firefox
      .on("wheel.zoom", null) // disables newer versions of Firefox
```